# Adding variable plus a number

Tags: batch-file

I am using a loop script and I was wondering how I can make the variable add 1 to each number as it goes here's what I have (this is just a snip):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (C:\bot\userpass.txt) do (
 set /a Number=%Number%+1
 Echo Starting Bot #%Number%
 START Client.exe %Config% %%a %%b %Server%
 PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %DelayTime% >NUL
)
```

Only when it echos it doesn't display the correct number, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable delayed expansion and use `!!`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in (C:\bot\userpass.txt) do (
 set /a Number=!Number!+1
 Echo Starting Bot #!Number!
 START Client.exe !Config! %%a %%b !Server!
 PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w !DelayTime! >NUL
)
```